# my server is loading plain HTML only, no css or js files

Tags: laravel, centos

Im hosting a laravel app on a CentOS VPS and I use git, after pushing some modifications and checking the site suddenly the site stoped loading local files like css and js (404 not found) but yet loading external files from CDNS like bootstrap and jquery...
Please advice

**snippet of code from the head of master page**

```
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png')}}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="{{asset('assets/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png')}}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png')}}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/favicon-96x96.png')}}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/shutter-modal.css')}}">
    <link rel="manifest" href="{{asset('assets/favicons/manifest.json')}}">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="{{asset('assets/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png')}}">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="_token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

{{-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/all.css")}}'> --}}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/themify-icons.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")}}'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/magnific-popup.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/owl.carousel.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/owl.theme.default.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/animate.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css")}}'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{asset("assets/css/style-MF.css")}}'>
```

and as I said this was ok and I didnt touch it in any way !

Comment: can you post the code where you are loading the css files into your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using root to update your code, change owner of your files to website user. You can use ***chown*** command to change owner and **-R** argument for applying recursively.

```
chown -R groupname:username *
```

**Note**: In most of time, groupname and username are same!

Comment: Web server needs to execution permission to serve files. By default web server access to file with website user and 644 permission. So you can set execution permission for every user or change file owner. (for more details, read about linux permission)